Has Israel commented on the halt on medical evacuations from Gaza in May 2024?
As of April 9 2024, a brief article in the medical journal The Lancet reported:

Israel is approving medical evacuation lists from Gaza. Once permission is granted, patients and accompanying people can travel to the Rafah border and obtain clearance to enter Egypt. They are then taken charge of by the North Sinai Health Services.

A month later on May 7, Israel closed the Rafah crossing. In the month since then (according to Reuters, citing the World Health Organization), no medical evacuations have been allowed.
Have any Israeli officials acknowledged this, explained why, or addressed it in any way?
